# Custom Page Template not working when site moved from subfolder

Tags: page-template, htaccess

I have been testing and redesigning my site in a subfolder: http://theseattlevine.com/wordpress2013

Today I am launching the site and have followed these instructions (http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) to make the subfolder display as the main site. I have done this many times before without issue.

Everything seems to be working fine except for one of my page templates.

If you go to the new site, now at http://theseattlevine.com the "Publish" button from the main nav is throwing a 404 error. I have that page set up to use a custom template called "publishing center" but for some reason it is not working on the new setup (it worked fine before).

I have tried resetting permalinks as well as completely deleting the .htaccess file and then re-saving permalinks, and it's still not working. All of my posts and other pages seem to work fine.

I can't figure out what's wrong, can anyone give some insight?

Comment: If your "Publishing Center" page is accessible from the WordPress Dashboard > Pages, check if you are directed to the correct page from there.
Also check that you don't have a category or tag named "Publish" since that can cause a re-write rules conflict.

Comment: When I click "view" from the Publish page on the admin side I am getting the same behavior. It loads my index template with a 404 error. I have no categories or tags called "publish" currently.

Comment: Actually, just realized it's loading the index page from the twenty eleven theme instead of from my custom theme... I wonder if that means something.

Comment: Figured it out!! I had a random WP install in a folder called "Publish" in my root that I had added months ago and then forgot about! I deleted it and it fixed everything. So dumb. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: Glad you worked it out!